# triggering the ngSubmit about mat-select box checkboxes

Tags: angular, angular-forms

My form ( which is a template-driven Angular 4+ form ) has a typical-submit button. You click on it, ngSubmit fires and off we go.

Now, there is a requirement. If the user selects one of the checkboxes on the mat-select options, boom, they want the form to submit too?

It sounds like it's got something to do with `optionSelectionChanges` but could not get it to a working state.

https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

Comment: You could call your ngOnSubmit method when the user selects one of the checkboxes

Comment: is it like (click)="ngOnsubmit()" on the mat-option? 
                <mat-option *ngFor="let learnerType of learnerTypeOptions" [value]="learnerType" (click)="ngOnsubmit()">{{ learnerType }}</mat-option>

Comment: call whatever your form submit method is. similar to `<form (ngSubmit)="yourMethod()">...</form>`. sorry I meant `ngSubmit` in my first comment